# sql server join table with translation table

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables as such:

```
ID   Name    indicator_1   indicator_2
1    text         1               1
2    text         1               1
3    text         1               1
4    text         2               1
5    text         2               1
6    text         2               2
7    text         2               2
8    text         3               2

FieldName    Value    Description
indicator_1    1         good
indicator_1    2         medium
indicator_1    3         bad
indicator_2    1         yes
indicator_2    2         no
```

Is there any way to join the two tables and arrive at:

```
ID   Name    indicator_1   indicator_2
1    text         good               yes
2    text         good               yes
3    text         good               yes
4    text         medium             yes
5    text         medium             yes
6    text         medium             no
7    text         medium             no
8    text         bad                no
```

This is just a sample, the actual table has about 70 indicators...thanks much

Comment: Thanks, sorry first time posting here.  My original plain text post threw off all the sample table views, i'll edit back to original plain text

Comment: do you want a solution to return all 70 indicators? Or are you only going to need a few of the indicators?

Comment: Yes, a solution for all 70.  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name, t2a.Description, t2b.Description
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2a ON t2a.FieldName = 'indicator_1' AND t2a.Value = t1.indicator_1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2b ON t2b.FieldName = 'indicator_2' AND t2b.Value = t1.indicator_2
```

Depending on your actual data, you may want to change "INNER" to "LEFT", but an INNER JOIN is probably right here.